# My social icons aren't aligning with content above

Tags: html, css, flexbox, icons

I've tried a few things here. I created the content in its own ul class, I've tried it inside the hero_text div, I've used this first snippet below and I have also explored other flexbox justify-content and align items. I've looked through the code for any errant margin-left but I didn't find anything that looked like it was impacting this.

I originally had these social links in the footer, and the issue persisted. I thought that trying it in another area I could attempt to find the problem and fix it, but I have not been able to figure it out.

```
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I analyzed all of this and rest of code which is also present on your github account.
there are only some line of code was missing:

```
        <!--footer-->
<aside> 
        <footer> 
      <ul class="social-media"> 
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/vicdearanzeta" target="_blank"><img src="Logo/mdi_linkedin.svg" width="32px" height="32px" class="linkedin" alt="linkedin"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://github.com/vdaranze" target="_blank"><img src="Logo/mdi_github.svg" width="32px" height="32px" class="github" alt="github"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.artstation.com/vicdearanzeta" target="_blank"><img src="Logo/mdi_artstation.svg" width="32px" height="32px" class="artstation" alt="artstation"></a></li>
      </ul>
   <p class="copyright">&copy;2023 Vic de Aranzeta</p>
</footer>
</aside>
```

In html File i just added a class in ul class="social-media" and then i applied CSS on this. In CSS file added code is given below:

```
.social-media{
    display: flex;
    /* border: 5px solid white; */
    justify-content: center;
}
```

This Will solve your Icons Align Problem.

```
    .copyright{
    text-align: center;
}
```

This line you can also add if you want to make this line of code(written below) center with icons.

```
enter code here
<p class="copyright">&copy;2023 Vic de Aranzeta</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is padding. The user agent stylesheet (aka browser default) includes a declaration of `padding-inline-start: 40px` for `ul`

Also, don't forget to remove the list marker using `list-style-type: none`

```css
.hero_text ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_text">
    <p class="name">Kaixo! I'm Vic de Aranzeta. </p>
    <p> A Design Anthropologist, User Experience Designer, Photographer, and Illustrator based in <s>sunny</s> foggy San Francisco.
    I'm a Principal Product Designer by day - Outside of work you can find me snapping photos on my Fujifilm X-T30II, playing video games, or reading a book.
Check out my <u><a href="https://www.vicdearanzeta.com" class="link">design portfolio</a></u> to see more work. This website is to practice front-end web development.</p>
   <ul> 
    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/vicdearanzeta" target="_blank"><img src="Logo/mdi_linkedin.svg" width="32px" height="32px" class="linkedin" alt="linkedin"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://github.com/vdaranze" target="_blank"><img src="Logo/mdi_github.svg" width="32px" height="32px" class="github" alt="github"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.artstation.com/vicdearanzeta" target="_blank"><img src="Logo/mdi_artstation.svg" width="32px" height="32px" class="artstation" alt="artstation"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```